# How to add a different version of сmake (3.27.0-rc4) to build.gradle

Tags: react-native, cmake

I'm doing a React Native project. I need to add another version cmake. I downloaded and installed the new version from https://cmake.org/download/

What is the correct way to put it in the file build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        firebaseMessagingVersion = "+"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
                if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
                    // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
                    ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
                } else {
                    // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
                    ndkVersion = "23.2.8568313"
                }

    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.2")

        // Add those lines
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        classpath("com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.15")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy {
            // Remove this override in 0.66, as a proper fix is included in react-native itself.
            force "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.70.0"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android");
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist");
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }

        maven {
            url "http://build-jcp/android_repository/";
            allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
        url 'https://www.jitpack.io';
        allowInsecureProtocol = true
        }
    }
}

ext {
    // Если есть доступ к репозиторию "http://build-jcp/jcp_rep",
    // то нужно указывать номер актуальной ревизии.
    // Можно указать пустую строку, если нет доступа к репозиторию
    // или используется локальная сборка JCP.
    revision = '.42396-release-android-20210119'
    ANDROID_VERSION='5.0'
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

What else needs to be done to connect the new version cmake. I have already registered the PATH and cmake is available from anywhere